# How to send request from XMLHTTP without waiting for the response?

Tags: asp-classic

```
pXML= Product_Request
set http= server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", "http://test.com/Data_Check/Request.asp?XML_File=" & pXML , False
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.send
```

I need to send request with above asp code for the above URL. But i no need response from that server.

After sending the request, it waits for the response.
How do I write this so that it doesn't block while waiting for the response?

Comment: BTW, Wish I earnt a quid everytime I see that Content-Type header being sent with a "GET" request.  Since by definition a GET doesn't carry any content there is little point specifying its type.

Comment: My first thought would be: com-visible .net component to handle the async part. Async within ASP classic is the realm of Heisenbugs.

Answer (score 2):

Change your Open request to Asynchronous (i.e. 3rd parameter to True). This will allow you to submit two requests at the same time. Then you get wait for both responses to arrive.

```
pXML = Product_Request
Set http = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", "http://test.com/Data_Check/Request.asp?XML_File=" & pXML , True
http.Send
Set http2 = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
http2.Open "GET", insert_code_for_your_second_url_here , True
http2.Send
http1.WaitForResponse
http2.WaitForResponse
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the [WinHTTPRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object directly instead (this is what underlies ServerXMLHTTP).  It has an additional method which might be useful the `WaitForResponse` method.

```
 Set winHttpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1") 
 winHttpRequest.Open "GET", "http://localhost/mypage.aspx", true

 winHttpRequest.Send

 ''# Do other request normally here

 winHttpRequest.WaitForResponse()
```

Note the `Open` method has `true` for its `async` parameter.  In this case `Send` will return as soon as the request has been sent but before any response has been recieved.  You can now do other things like make your other request in a normal synchronous manner.  Once done you can make sure that the orginal request has completed by calling `WaitForResponse`.

**CAVEATs**

- I've never done this on in ASP directly there is possibility that the call to `Open` might complain that the script environment doesn't "do asynchronous calls".
- There is an assumption on your part that it is ok to make the two requests at the same time.  If they are to two different servers then that will be fine, if not its still possibly fine but there may be other complications.
- You are making requests to an ASP page, each request creates a new session on that server, just something to be aware of.
- There is an assumption on my part you aren't calling into the same server that your code is running on, if you are you may be headed for a thread pool dead lock.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to determine that your request was successful without a response. So what's to determine the difference between no response and complete failure?

Comment: i need to send 1st request and go to the next request.  response i need to generate in my another server. Problem for me is.. 1st request take 10 sec to get replay and 2nd response take 15 sec to get replay. total 25 sec take. i need to do this to in 15 sec...

Comment: Does request 2 require that request 1 completes first?

Comment: i need to send two request and weight for the response of that two request together.. because i need to finish response in min time

Comment: AJAX, being asynchronous, allows you to fire both requests without waiting, capture the responses in the callback and you can move forward from there.

Comment: Anthony seems to be better at this. I gave up Classic ASP 10 years ago.

Comment: @Diodeus:  "allows you to fire both requests without waiting" the script will have to wait on at least one of them and then on the one that still hasn't finished.  Otherwise the script will just end.